# How to check header exist before import data in Ruby CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

I want to write header only 1 time in first row when import data to csv in ruby, but the header is written many time on output file.

```
job_datas.each do |job_data|
    @company_job = job data coverted etc....
    save_job_to_csv(@company_job)
end


def save_job_to_csv(job_data)
    filepath = "tmp/jobs/jobs.csv"
    CSV.open(filepath, "a", :headers => true) do |csv|
        if csv.blank?
            csv << CompanyJob.attribute_names
        end
        csv << job_data.attributes.values
    end
end
```

Any one can give me solution? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to this:

```rb
def save_job_to_csv(job_data)
    filepath = "tmp/jobs/jobs.csv"
    
    unless File.file?(filepath)
        File.open(filepath, 'w') do |file|
            file.puts(job_data.attribute_names.join(','))
        end 
    end

    CSV.open(filepath, "a", :headers => true) do |csv|
        csv << job_data.attributes.values
    end
end
```

It just checks beforehand if the file exists and if not it adds the header. If you want tabs as column separators, you just have to change the value for the join function and add the col_sep parameter to CSV.open():

```rb
file.puts(job_data.attribute_names.join("\t"))

CSV.open(filepath, "a", :headers => true, col_sep: "\t") do |csv|
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `save_job_to_csv` the method for each `job_data` and pushing header every time `csv << CompanyJob.attribute_names`

```
filepath = "tmp/jobs/jobs.csv"
CSV.open(filepath, "a", :headers => true) do |csv|
  # push header once
  csv << CompanyJob.attribute_names

  # push every job record
  job_datas.each do |job_data|
    @company_job = job data coverted etc....
    csv << @company_job.attributes.values
  end
end
```

The above script can be created wrapped a method but if you like to write a separate method that just saves the CSV, then you need to refactor the script when you first prepare an array of values holding header and pass it to a method that just saves to CSV.

Comment: if i want to call save_job_to_csv  function in each time to write csv, have no way to check header exist in this file, right?

Comment: It is bad practice to check the header just to avoid adding to the CSV multiple time. I could have provided the solution but the purpose of SO is to guide you, not providing ready-to-use solutions.